# deleteAll with conditions and a delete limit

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

CakePHP Version: 4.2.6

Xampp:
Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1l PHP/8.0.11
Server version: 10.4.21-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
PHP version: 8.0.11

**Introduction**

I'm trying to construct a deleteAll query with the order by and limit clauses.

**SQL**

When the following sql is run in the xampp sql tab window it deletes just one row in the correct order which is what I wanted it to do.

```
DELETE FROM `report_dashs` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1;
```

**API Documentation**

I'd like to replicate this using deleteAll with conditions. I've referenced [this](https://api.cakephp.org/4.2/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#deleteAll()) in the api
documentation:

deleteAll(mixed $conditions)

Parameters
mixed $conditions
Conditions to be used, accepts anything Query::where() can take.

Returns
int
Returns the number of affected rows.

**What I've tried**

On the basis of this I've constructed the following query:

```
$this->ReportDashs->deleteAll(
    [
        'user_id' => 1001
    ])
    ->order(['id' => 'DESC'])
    ->limit(1);
```

This throws an error:

Call to a member function order() on int

This line `->order(['id' => 'DESC'])`

and deleteAll returns an int.

**Summary**

I've tried numerous configurations but every attempt has either thrown a syntax error or deleted
all the rows. The debug kit sql log is always missing the order and limit clause.

**Question**

How do you construct the deleteAll query and respect the order by and limit clause.

**Note**

If the full stack trace will help let me know and I'll post it.

Thanks,
Zenzs.

---

**Solutions**

**Attempt with eager loading and a custom finder:**

// Controller:

```
$query = $this->ReportDashs->find('clearSuperuserData', [
    'contain' => ['Users'],
    'client_id' => 1234
])
->delete()
->epilog('ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1')
->execute();
```

// Finder:

```
public function findClearSuperuserData(Query $query, array $options): object
{
    $query
        ->where(['Users.client_id' => $options['client_id']]);
    return $query;
}
```

But the Users table was never respected in the where clause.

**Attempt without eager loading and a custom finder:**

```
$query = $this->ReportDashs
    ->find()
    ->where(['user_id' => 1003])
    ->delete()
    ->epilog('ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1')
    ->execute();
```

And this deletes the correct rows in order with the limit applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the API docs for [**`Table::deleteAll()`**](https://api.cakephp.org/4.2/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#deleteAll()), it's a convenience method for deleting all records that match the given conditions, and it will return the number of affected rows.

For more complex queries you can generally use the query builder, however currently `ORDER` and `LIMIT` are not supported for `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries. [**The last attempt to implement it**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/9730) in a cross-DBMS fashion was unfortunately abandoned.

Currently you can either use completely raw SQL, or in your specific case for MariaDB/MySQL, you could use the query builder's epilog to append the `ORDER` and `LIMIT` clauses:

```php
$query = $this->ReportDashs
    ->query()
    ->delete()
    ->epilog('ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1');
```

or

```php
$query = $this->ReportDashs
    ->query()
    ->delete()
    ->epilog(
        $this->ReportDashs
            ->getConnection()
            ->newQuery()
            ->orderDesc('id')
            ->limit(1)
    );
```

Both would generate

```sql
DELETE FROM report_dashs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

the latter with support for automatic identifier quoting.

Alternatively, if you're feeling adventurous, you could create an extended query compiler that enables compiling the required clauses, `\Cake\Database\QueryCompiler::$_deleteParts` is what would need to be modified to include the `order` and `limit` part.

Comment: Thanks they both deleted the correct rows. I implemented your first solution but used find() to create the query object so I could apply the conditions. I also tried using eager loading because one of the conditions applied to a join table but I couldn't get the joined table to be recognised. The second solution when used with find() did not delete any rows so I unfortunately was not able to use that. The query compiler probably the way to go but I'll have to put that on the dev list. I posted my eager loading attempt and a working solution above.